# Caught Exception: Access denied in amazon order api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have created amazon seller account, and I have sign up for mws (market place webservices), and I got all my keys such as secret key, access key and all.
And now I downloaded first the amazon orders api it has come with a set of files.
Under `.config.inc.php` I gave all the credentials, and he has given some sample code under samples folder in that first I opened `GetOrderSample.php` and uncommented the Service Url as `$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";` after I run the file in browser it says:

> "Caught Exception: Access denied Response Status Code: 401 Error Code: AccessDenied Error Type: Sender Request ID: 606e9ead-fb70-4a60-a795-4fc601421c65 XML: Sender AccessDenied"

Please help me to solve this im stuck at this place from a long time.
This is the file code of GetOrderSample.php,

```
<?php
      /*******************************************************************************
       * Copyright 2009-2015 Amazon Services. All Rights Reserved.
       * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
       *
       * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
       * You may obtain a copy of the License at: http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
       * This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR 
       * CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the 
       * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
       *******************************************************************************
       * PHP Version 5
       * @category Amazon
       * @package  Marketplace Web Service Orders
       * @version  2013-09-01
       * Library Version: 2015-09-24
       * Generated: Fri Sep 25 20:06:28 GMT 2015
       */

      /**
       * Get Order Sample
       */

      require_once('.config.inc.php');

      /************************************************************************
       * Instantiate Implementation of MarketplaceWebServiceOrders
       *
       * AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY constants
       * are defined in the .config.inc.php located in the same
       * directory as this sample
       ***********************************************************************/
      // More endpoints are listed in the MWS Developer Guide
      // North America:
      $serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
      // Europe
      //$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
      // Japan
      //$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.jp/Orders/2013-09-01";
      // China
      //$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com.cn/Orders/2013-09-01";


       $config = array (
         'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
         'ProxyHost' => null,
         'ProxyPort' => -1,
         'ProxyUsername' => null,
         'ProxyPassword' => null,
         'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
       );

       $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client(
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
              APPLICATION_NAME,
              APPLICATION_VERSION,
              $config);

      /************************************************************************
       * Uncomment to try out Mock Service that simulates MarketplaceWebServiceOrders
       * responses without calling MarketplaceWebServiceOrders service.
       *
       * Responses are loaded from local XML files. You can tweak XML files to
       * experiment with various outputs during development
       *
       * XML files available under MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Mock tree
       *
       ***********************************************************************/
       // $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Mock();

      /************************************************************************
       * Setup request parameters and uncomment invoke to try out
       * sample for Get Order Action
       ***********************************************************************/
       // @TODO: set request. Action can be passed as MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_GetOrder
       $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_GetOrderRequest();
       $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
       // object or array of parameters
       invokeGetOrder($service, $request);

      /**
        * Get Get Order Action Sample
        * Gets competitive pricing and related information for a product identified by
        * the MarketplaceId and ASIN.
        *
        * @param MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service instance of MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface
        * @param mixed $request MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_GetOrder or array of parameters
        */

        function invokeGetOrder(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service, $request)
        {
            try {
              $response = $service->GetOrder($request);

              echo ("Service Response\n");
              echo ("=============================================================================\n");

              $dom = new DOMDocument();
              $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
              $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
              $dom->formatOutput = true;
              echo $dom->saveXML();
              echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

           } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Exception $ex) {
              echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
              echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
              echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
              echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
              echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
              echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
              echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
           }
       }
```

Comment: I have edited my post and code is there in that

Comment: Please any1 help me in this..

Comment: Yes its solved, i was using north america service url, i had to use europe service url....  its should be this                                                                     $serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please create an answer with your comment so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its solved, i was using north america service url, i had to use europe service url.... its should be this for india.

```
$serviceUrl = "mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon MWS Endpoint for india : `https://mws.amazonservices.in`

For more information [read](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html).